# Get a value and print text to a text field

Tags: java, jtextfield

well in this question I want the user to input a value in the first text field
the the user should press calculate.
To get the value that the user entered this line should do.

```
 int j = Integer.parseInt(s.getText());
```

but I have an error,

which says:Cannot refer to the non-final local variable s defined in an enclosing scope.

then I want to print y1 in the second text feild
but I do not know how to do that

```
 package ass3;

 import java.awt.FlowLayout;
 import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
 import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

 import java.awt.GridLayout;

 import javax.swing.JButton;
 import javax.swing.JFrame;
 import javax.swing.JLabel;
 import javax.swing.JTextField;
 import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

  public class secondsConvert {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("second convert program");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(8,2));
        JLabel seconds = new JLabel("Enter seconds",SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        frame.add(seconds);
        JTextField s = new JTextField(10);
        frame.add(s);
        JLabel year = new JLabel("Years",SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        frame.add(year);
        JTextField y = new JTextField(10);
        frame.add(y);
        JLabel week = new JLabel("Weeks",SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        frame.add(week);
        JTextField w = new JTextField(10);
        frame.add(w);
        JLabel day = new JLabel("Days",SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        frame.add(day);
        JTextField d = new JTextField(10);
        frame.add(d);
        JLabel hours = new JLabel("Hours",SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        frame.add(hours);
        JTextField h = new JTextField(10);
        frame.add(h);
        JLabel minuts = new JLabel("Minuts",SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        frame.add(minuts);
        JTextField m = new JTextField(10);
        frame.add(m);
        JLabel un = new JLabel("Seconds",SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        frame.add(un);
        JTextField u = new JTextField(10);
        frame.add(u);
        JButton b1 = new JButton("OK");
        frame.add(b1);
        JButton b2 = new JButton("Calculate");
        frame.add(b2);
        ActionListener act = new ActionListener(){
             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                 int j = Integer.parseInt(s.getText());
                 int y1=j/31536000;
                 int a=j%31536000;
             }
        };
        b2.addActionListener(act);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
}
  }
```

Comment: it work fine with me

Comment: it worked fine with my doctor too, but it did not worked with me untel i add the word final @YCF_L

Answer (score 6):

this answer is for your second question. If you want to print y1 in year(y textfield)  you should try like this. inside your act actionlistner after the calculation

```
 y.setText(Integer.toString(y1));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because

The problem is that anonymous inner classes make copies of local fields that they use, and if the fields are not final, then the copy may not be in sync with the original causing all sorts of problems.(Taken from         [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19104203/jtextfield-wants-to-be-a-final-when-i-try-to-use-gettext))

You have two options:
1. Declare variable before main method as like:

```
public class secondsConvert {

JTextField s = new JTextField(10);

public static void main(String[] args)
{
}
}
```

2. Declare variable as final:

   public static void main(String[] args)

   {

   final JTextField s = new JTextField(10);

   }